# C++: Tesseract tuning to remove noisy elements

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

I am trying to do some pre-processing on an image to get some text out of it but unfortunately there are still some "noisy" elements that are stuck on the image and they compromise the OCR.

Processed image:

[image: Processed image]

The main goal would be to only keep the text and remove those little black lines on the left:

[image: Black Lines]

Does anyone have an idea how to do so ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try a text detection algorithm, maybe MSER (never used it), then get a bounding box, and work from there

Answer (score 2):

you can use stroke width transform

an [example](https://sites.google.com/site/roboticssaurav/strokewidthnokia)

Answer (score 1):

First, apply erosion on the image (it is possible, that you need to experiment with size of kernel). After that dilate results back to recover.

For very thick line/pixel noise you should also apply median blur on it.

Comment: The problem with dilate is that even with the smallest kernel with Size(2;2) and a cross morphology it deletes lots of important characters. I guess the letters are already too thin to be processed with dilatation...